# ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token) using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.x

I have a rare problem I cant seem to wrap my head around, it is related to XML parsing using ElementTree in python.

Tried seaching for clues and answers regarding similar problems but to no help

My function:

```
def errorChecker(xmlResponse):
    xmlResponse = str(xmlResponse)
    xmlText = xmlParser.fromstring(xmlResponse)
    errorText = ""
    for xmlData in xmlText.iter():  
            print xmlData.tag
            if xmlData.tag == "fault":
                for errorData in xmlText.iter('code'):
                    #errorText = errorDict[errorData]
                    return errorData.text
    return False
```

When I pass this XML code it returns just fine:

```
"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
  <fault>
    <code>1055</code>
  </fault>
</response>"""
```

But when I get the XML directly from the server and pass it to the function I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wmsTest.py", line 556, in <module>
    errorChecker(str(location))
  File "wmsTest.py", line 134, in errorChecker
    xmlText = xmlParser.fromstring(str(xmlResponse))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1311, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1659, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1523, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 6, column 11
```

Added information about my server request:

I use requests to access the server. By using:

```
response = requests.post(appServer, data=xml)
print "raw from server"
print response.text
print "str response"
print str(response.text)
return response.text
```

the response is:

```
    raw from server
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
  <fault>
    <code>1055</code>
  </fault>
</response>
str response
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
  <fault>
    <code>1055</code>
  </fault>
</response>
```

Python interprets the incoming XML as type unicode, it is exactly the same as the manual XML code above as it is a print I only add the """ to start and end.

Any clues?

Comment: Show us the XML that does not work, not the XML that works. Either the server returns a malformed XML string or the `str` conversion breaks some characters.

Comment: the XML that works is what the server returns. It is copied from a print to cmd but I have added the """ before and after the XML. Thats it.

Comment: Added some information regarding my post to the server, maybe it can help with any clue?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some checks on the lengths that where returned I figured out that the servers return a longer response than expected, there is a space added to the end after . Removing the space cleared the problem!